# Random function does not work as i wish to

Tags: java

Im trying to make a Pacman, so im using an array[8][8], in which i have a PacMan, 2 ghosts, walls, and points that the Pacman can eat. as the pacman eats points you start to get empty spaces.

So i decidad to make a function random that ramdonly assign Fruits ONLY to the empty spaces, but the problem is that as more empty spaces you get the fruits start going crazy and appear all over my array. I would like to have always the same chances of getting fruits despite of the empty spaces i have.

Here are the methods im using, help please.

```
 public void AppearFruit()
{
    for(int i= 0; i<_world.length; i++){
        for(int j= 0; j<_world.length; j++){
            Random as = new Random(); 
            int fru = as.nextInt(20); 
            if(fru==10){
                if(_world[i][j] instanceof Empty){
                    _world[i][j] = new Fruit(i,j);  
                }  
            }           
        }
    }
}

public void DisappearFruit()
{

    for(int i= 0; i<_world.length; i++){
        for(int j= 0; j<_world.length; j++){
            if (_world[i][j] instanceof Fruit){
                if(contfru>=3) {
                    _mundo[i][j] = new Empty(i,j);
                    contfru=0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like homework, feels like homework... is it homework? Not but seriously, could you post your code in english at least?

Comment: Sorry we don't know how and when you invoke those 2 methods so hard to say what is happening. Btw, a method name should not start with a capital letter. And in your for loops, the sinner loop should test for condition j<_world[i].length. This only works because your array is "square".

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by "the same chance of getting fruits".

What you have now will independently give each empty space a 1 in 20 chance of getting a fruit.  So if you have a large grid with 2-300 empty spaces, you'd expect to get 10-15 fruits every time `AppearFruit` runs.

I don't know what the `contfru` variable is in `DisappearFruit`, but I would imagine it's not getting rid of the fruits at anywhere near this rate - so that over time, more and more fruits will appear.

**Edit**: After your update, you're asking for

> the same chances of getting fruits despite of the empty spaces i have

By definition, this means that your current approach can't work at all, because you give *each space* an equal chance of getting fruit.  Doubling the number of empty spaces will double the number of fruits you get (on average).

It sounds like you want something more like a method to add **one** fruit, which scans the array of empty spaces and assigns the fruit to one of the spaces at random.  Then you can tweak how often you call this method - maybe it happens exactly every 50 turns, maybe it happens every `30 + rnd(40)` turns, maybe every 60 seconds, etc.  You can tweak how much fruit appears (and how quickly) through the frequency of the calls.

Comment: that sounds like a better idea than scanning each space, how can i do that?

Comment: and what i mean with contfru, it is an int variable that and i use it to disappear the fruit after 3 turns

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I get why you get many fruits. In your method `AppearFruit`, when you assign a Fruit, you don't increment countfru, making you method `DisappearFruit`never work like intended

Answer (score 0):

Right now the probabilty for a fruit to appear is 5% for each empty field and *for each move*. Like you have one empty field and move the pacman 10 times, the probability for *this* field is

```
 P_fruit = 1 - (19/20)^10
         = 40.1%
```

I guess, the algorithm is not bad, you may call it far to often.

**Edit**

You could tweak the behaviour by using a far lower probability, but in the end, it would be the same: if you need more fruit, simply keep the pacman moving.

I'd disconnect the fruit generation from movement. Think about a timer instead - like every 30 seconds an event is triggered that generates fruit on empty spaces with a low probability. You could even say: I define a probability *p* that *one fruit* is generated on the board and *then* randomly choose one of the current empty spaces: (pseudocode)

```
 placeFruit(board)
    if (random() > 5%) return;   // no fruit this time
    List fields :== getAllEmptyFields(board);
    fruitField :== random(fields.size());
    fruitField.add(new Fruit());
```

Comment: dont you think that the probabilities are to high? it is supossed that the times that a fruit appear are counted, how can i get lower probabilities?